# I want to add a single file to github without having to add additional folders in the same clone repo

Tags: git, github, version-control, github-for-windows

I have cloned a repository from online and have it locally. Now, I wan't to upload a single folder that contains code to my virtual repo on github without adding the other files within the cloned repository. I plan to work on the code, and commit/push it as I work. I don't wan't to delete the rest of the files in the cloned repo because they still have a use for me, but not to people who will be seeing my code on Github.

Comment: You can only push up sets of commits.  If you don't want to remove the old files, then don't push commits that delete them.

Comment: I want upload my local version of https://github.com/adnanaziz/EPIJudge/tree/master/epi_judge_java/epi, not the whole repository (https://github.com/adnanaziz/EPIJudge)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Choose just this files or folder where you want to push. As example:

```
git add thisFile.txt
git commit -m "add just one file from local to remote"
git push
```

So you can add just this files to github where the people there allowed to look at. And this files, where you don‘t want on github, you may never `add` to github.

Another way to achieve that files not pushes to *github* is `.gitignore`. Write all files in `.gitignore`-file where you don‘t want to push to *github*. The advantage is, that you never see this files by entering `git status`. Without `.gitignore` you will see everytime all files (also this files where you don't want to push on *github*) as *new file* with `git status`. Gitignore documentation [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore)